# condition comparing two parameter values in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a template file in which I am trying to conditionally include a task if 2 parameter values are same.  First parameter value is passed from pipeline to template and the other parameter is defined within the template.  For some reason the comparison fails.  What's issue with the following comparison ?

```
Calling Pipeline
----------------
trigger: none

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

stages:
  - stage: RunContainers
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            upgradeVersion="$(ls -l utils/upgrade | grep ^d | sed 's,.*run_,,g' | sort -nr | head -1)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=upgradeVersion;]$upgradeVersion"
          displayName: 'Get Latest upgrade version'

        # Output of above task sets upgradeVersion to 5

        - template: pipeline-templates/run-upgrade-template.yml
          parameters:
            LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL: $(LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL)
            LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME: $(LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME)
            LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD: $(LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD)
            rollback: false
            versionList: [$(upgradeVersion)]

Template file
-------------
# File Name : run-upgrade-template.yml
parameters:
- name: versionList
  type: object
  default: ['1']

# Map of upgrade version to number of liquibase changesets
- name: LiquibaseChangesetMap
  type: object
  default:
    - versionNumber: '1'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    - versionNumber: '2'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [8]
    - versionNumber: '3'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [9]
    - versionNumber: '4'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [10]
    - versionNumber: '5'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [11, 12]

steps:
- ${{ each version in parameters.versionList }}:
  - script: echo "Comparing version ${{ version }}"
  - ${{ each map in parameters.LiquibaseChangesetMap }}:
      - script: echo "Comparing version ${{ version }} and ${{ map.versionNumber }}"
      - ${{ if eq('${{ map.versionNumber }}', '${{ version }}') }}:
        - script: |
            echo "Found version to upgrade"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionMapExists;]true"
          displayName: Verion Map is true
        - template: run-liquibase-update.yml
          parameters:
            changeset: ${{ map.changesets }}
```

The task Found version to upgrade is never executed.  I tried the comparison using the following statement and that also fails.

```
      - ${{ if eq(map.versionNumber, version) }}:
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Several things are wrong in your pipeline, starting with your parameters, you are redefining your -versionNumber parameters serveral times, secondly, in order to access parameters you MUST prefix parameters with ${{ parameters.PARAM_NAME }}, at last, you must set your variable 'versionMapExists' as an output variable, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547020/azure-pipeline-pass-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/72549723#72549723

Answer (score 0):

The elements that previous expression got don't need to use `${{}}` any more.

These YAML should works:

**main.yml**

```
steps:
- template: sub.yml

  parameters:
    versionList: ['1','2']
```

**sub.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: versionList
  type: object
  default: ['1']
# Map of upgrade version to number of liquibase changesets
- name: LiquibaseChangesetMap
  type: object
  default:
    - versionNumber: '1'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    - versionNumber: '2'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [8]
    - versionNumber: '3'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [9]
    - versionNumber: '4'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [10]
    - versionNumber: '5'
      changesetType: 'number'
      changesets: [11, 12]

steps:
- ${{ each version in parameters.versionList }}:
      - ${{ each map in parameters.LiquibaseChangesetMap }}:
            - ${{ if eq(map.versionNumber, version) }}:
                  - script: |
                      echo ${{ version }}
                      echo ${{ map.versionNumber }}
                    displayName: Verion ${{ version }} is same as map version ${{ map.versionNumber }}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  In your case, you are hardcoding versionList values in main.yml.  I don't want to hard code the version values.  I want to get it from one or more variables, create a list and pass it as parameter

Comment: Because the conditions are evaluated during pipeline pre-processing stage, looks like it's not possible to use variables.