# Set variable from a python script and use it in multiple jobs and template

Tags: python, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline, created using the YAML syntax.
In this pipeline, I have a step that is going to execute a python script using PowerShell, then get the return value and save it in a variable so I can use it in the other jobs (inside some templates)

```
jobs:
  - job: job_name
    variables:
      myVariable: 'default-value'
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "set variable from script"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host $(.\script.py)
            New-Variable -Name "MY_VARIABLE" -Value $(.\script.py)
            Write-Host "Variable from script is: $MY_VARIABLE"

            Write-Host "Global variable is: ${{ variables.myVariable }}"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable]$MY_VARIABLE"
            Write-Host "Global variable is now: ${{ variables.myVariable }}"

  - template: .ci/other-job.yml
    parameters:
      input: ${{ variables.myVariable}}
```

The python script is getting some stuff from another file and then returning the value like this:

```py
result = "XYZ"
print(result)
return result
```

The `MY_VARIABLE` is getting the correct value **XYZ**, but when I try to assign it to the variable `myVariable` it doesn't work. The problem I have is that `myVariable` always has **default-value** instead of having the value **XYZ**.

How can I fix that without using job parameters, because the value is unknown until runtime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops suggests that `${{ variables.myVariable }}` is expanded at _compile time_, so it won't see the value updated at runtime. _Perhaps_ `$(myVariable)` works (I don't enough about Azure to be sure).

Comment: I think your question can be answered in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547020/azure-pipeline-pass-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/72549723#72549723

Answer (score 0):

Logging command value can only get after the current task.

**py file:**

```
import os
def my_function():
    result = "XYZ"
    print(result)
    return result
my_function()
```

**yml file:**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
variables:
      myVariable: 'default-value'
      one: initialValue 

steps:
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue"
- pwsh: |
      $ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
      $ProcessInfo.FileName = "pythonw.exe"
      $ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
      $ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
      $ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
      $ProcessInfo.Arguments = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\returnvalue.py"
      $Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
      $Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
      $Process.Start() | Out-Null
      $Process.WaitForExit()
      $stdout = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
      # $stderr = $Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
      $MY_VARIABLE = $stdout #+ $stderr
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable]$MY_VARIABLE"
- pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Global variable is now: $(myVariable)"
```

Get it:

[image]

Comment: Note that the PowerShell code that populates `$MY_VARIABLE` can be reduced to this: `$MY_VARIIABLE = .\script.py`