# Variables which value is a variable name in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have following tasks in a pipeline (Azure DevOps). First task read a secret from a KeyVault using a variable `$(mySecretName)` which value is `secret-name`. Second task needs to pass the value of the read secret to a ARM:

```yaml
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Read secret'
  inputs:
     azureSubscription: $(mySubscription)
     KeyVaultName: $(myKeyVault)
     SecretsFilter: $(mySecretName)
     RunAsPreJob: false

- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Use secret value'
  inputs:
     resourceGroupName: $(myResourceGroup)
     location: $(myLocation)
     azureResourceManagerConnection: $(mySubscription)
     templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
     csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/cd-template.json'
     overrideParameters: >
        -secretValue "$($(mySecretName))"
     deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

In line `-secretValue "$($(mySecretName))"` I'm trying to resolve in this way but apparently it does not work: `$(mySecretName)` -> `$(secret-name)` -> `secret value`. If I use `$(secret-name)` it will work, but I need to use `$(mySecretName)` because the name will change depending on the environment.

Is there any solution that allows me to get the value of a variable which name is the value of another variable?

Comment: Maybe it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547020/azure-pipeline-pass-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/72549723#72549723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your YAML sample, you are using nested variables `$($(mySecretName))`. It is not yet supported in the pipelines.

To achieve your requirement, you can use the Variable Set  task from extension: [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks).

You can add the Variable Set task before the AzureResourceGroupDeployment task.

For example:

```
steps
- task: VariableSetTask@2
  displayName: 'Set variable: kevin to: ''$($(test))'''
  inputs:
    variableName: NewVariable
    Value: '$($(mySecretName))'

- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Use secret value'
  inputs:
     resourceGroupName: $(myResourceGroup)
     location: $(myLocation)
     azureResourceManagerConnection: $(mySubscription)
     templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
     csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/cd-template.json'
     overrideParameters: >
        -secretValue "$(NewVariable)"
     deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to use nested *variables*, but you can nest a *parameter* in a variable. Thus, if you pass `mySecretName` as a parameter, you can do this:

```
${{ parameters.mySecretName }}

SecretsFilter: $(${{ parameters.mySecretName }})
```

This is apparently because a pre-processor substitutes the parameter value before execution.